# Problems to make a function that rollsNDice in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, state

I'm experimenting with randomness in Haskell and I wanted to do a function that given an Int n returns a list of states of random numbers between 1 and 6:

```
-- auxiliar function
rollDie :: State StdGen Int
rollDie = do generator <- get
                let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator
                put newGenerator
                return value

rollNDice :: Int -> State StdGen [Int]
rollNDice n | n == 0    = [] :: State StdGen [Int]
  | otherwise = (:) <$> rollDie <*> rollNDice (n-1)
```

but when I try to run it in ghci I get:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’
                     with ‘StateT StdGen Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Int]’
      Expected type: State StdGen [Int]
        Actual type: [a0]
    • In the expression: [] :: State StdGen [Int]
      In an equation for ‘rollNDice’:
          rollNDice n
            | n == 0 = [] :: State StdGen [Int]
            | otherwise = (:) <$> rollDie <*> rollNDice (n - 1)
```

I don't understand the error. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `return []`, or `pure []`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because `[]` has type `[a]`, you can not use `[] :: State StdGen [Int]` to convert it to a `State StdGen [Int]`.

You can however use [**`pure :: Applicative m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure) to wrap this in a `State StdGen [Int]`:

```
rollNDice :: Int -> State StdGen [Int]
rollNDice 0 = pure []
rollNDice n = (:) <$> rollDie <*> rollNDice (n-1)
```

That being said, you can make use of [**`replicateM :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) here to generate a list of `n` items:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

rollNDice :: Int -> State StdGen [Int]
rollNDice = (`replicateM` rollDie)
```

For example:

```
Prelude System.Random Control.Monad.Trans.State Control.Monad> evalState (rollNDice 5) (mkStdGen 0)
[6,6,4,1,5]
```